# INVALID RESOURCE ID paypal Subcription update plan

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, paypal

i have this problem. (I try to update a subrcription on sanbox from one plan to another plan) - Same product, amount different.

I call rest api POST :

https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/(SubscptionId)/revise

- I have insert correct ACCESS TOKEN and correct PLAN ID (Active).

On visual studio debug it working and paypal response 200.

When i try to use on Azure web api (on logger i have this error on json)

```
issues="INVALID_RESOURCE_ID"
description =" Requested resource ID was not found."
```

But the resource id is not required on request field.

Someone know how i can resolve?

Thanks in advance.

REQUEST:

SUBSCRIPTION ACTIVATED WEBHOOK RESPONSE

response webhook paypal

```
{
       "id": "WH-05X15924JM439863B-0A754578Y3494494Y",

       "create_time": "2022-06-17T09:57:07.299Z",

       "resource_type": "subscription",

       "event_type": "BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED",

       "summary": "Subscription activated",

       "resource": {

              "quantity": "1",

              "subscriber": {

                     "email_address": sb-m4dxd17050716@personal.example.com,

                     "payer_id": "HNJDGM4CVQWDQ",

                     "name": {

                            "given_name": "John",

                            "surname": "Doe"

                     },

                     "shipping_address": {

                            "address": {

                                   "address_line_1": "Via Unit? d'Italia",

                                   "admin_area_2": "Napoli",

                                   "admin_area_1": "Napoli",

                                   "postal_code": "80127",

                                   "country_code": "IT"

                            }

                     }

              },

              "create_time": "2022-06-17T09:56:58Z",

              "plan_overridden": false,

              "shipping_amount": {

                     "currency_code": "EUR",

                     "value": "0.0"

              },

              "start_time": "2022-06-17T09:56:40Z",

              "update_time": "2022-06-17T09:56:59Z",

              "billing_info": {

                     "outstanding_balance": {

                            "currency_code": "EUR",

                            "value": "0.0"

                     },

                     "cycle_executions": [

                            {

                                   "tenure_type": "REGULAR",

                                   "sequence": 1,

                                   "cycles_completed": 1,

                                   "cycles_remaining": 0,

                                   "current_pricing_scheme_version": 1,

                                   "total_cycles": 0

                            }

                     ],

                     "last_payment": {

                            "amount": {

                                   "currency_code": "EUR",

                                   "value": "50.0"

                            },

                            "time": "2022-06-17T09:56:58Z"

                     },

                     "next_billing_time": "2022-06-19T10:00:00Z",

                     "failed_payments_count": 0

              },

              "links": [

                     {

                            "href": https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-3J5HHBY1JHMC/cancel,

                            "rel": "cancel",

                            "method": "POST",

                            "encType": "application/json"

                     },

                     {

                            "href": https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-3J5HHBY1JHMC,

                            "rel": "edit",

                            "method": "PATCH",

                            "encType": "application/json"

                     },

                     {

                            "href": https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-3J5HHBY1JHMC,

                            "rel": "self",

                            "method": "GET",

                            "encType": "application/json"

                     },

                     {

                            "href": https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-3J5HHBY1JHMC/suspend,

                            "rel": "suspend",

                            "method": "POST",

                            "encType": "application/json"

                     },

                     {

                            "href": https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-3J5HHBY1JHMC/capture,

                            "rel": "capture",

                            "method": "POST",

                            "encType": "application/json"

                     }

              ],

              "id": "I-3J5HHBY1JHMC",

              "plan_id": "P-8SG32020HB3302043MKVTYZY",

              "status": "ACTIVE",

              "status_update_time": "2022-06-17T09:56:59Z"

       },

       "status": "SUCCESS",

       "transmissions": [

              {

                     "webhook_url": https://regolari.azurewebsites.net/RegolariCaller,

                     "http_status": 200,

                     "reason_phrase": "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established",

                     "response_headers": {

                            "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",

                            "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",

                            "Connection": "keep-alive",

                            "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinitySameSite=2989c34f7c0cdb7ec5c37c2d6a0cd07c20c702dc389fc83ca79bfb532ef0320f;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=regolari.azurewebsites.net",

                            "Date": "Fri, 17 Jun 2022 09:57:44 GMT",

                            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                            "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET"

                     },

                     "transmission_id": "e87042a0-ee23-11ec-8079-f5b1270d17b4",

                     "status": "SUCCESS",

                     "timestamp": "2022-06-17T09:57:33Z"

              }

       ],

       "links": [

              {

                     "href": https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-05X15924JM439863B-0A754578Y3494494Y,

                     "rel": "self",

                     "method": "GET",

                     "encType": "application/json"

              },

              {

                     "href": https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-05X15924JM439863B-0A754578Y3494494Y/resend,

                     "rel": "resend",

                     "method": "POST",

                     "encType": "application/json"

              }

       ],

       "event_version": "1.0",

       "resource_version": "2.0"

}
```

PAYMENT SALED COMPLETED WEBHOOK

```
{
      "id": "WH-3YN53862H3003372E-77V7032476059723Y",
      "create_time": "2022-06-17T09:57:17.044Z",
      "resource_type": "sale",
      "event_type": "PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED",
      "summary": "Payment completed for EUR 50.0 EUR",
      "resource": {
             "billing_agreement_id": "I-3J5HHBY1JHMC",
             "amount": {
                    "total": "50.00",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "details": {
                           "subtotal": "50.00"
                    }
             },
             "payment_mode": "INSTANT_TRANSFER",
             "update_time": "2022-06-17T09:56:58Z",
             "create_time": "2022-06-17T09:56:58Z",
             "protection_eligibility_type": "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE",
             "transaction_fee": {
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "value": "2.05"
             },
             "protection_eligibility": "ELIGIBLE",
             "links": [
                    {
                           "method": "GET",
                           "rel": "self",
                           "href": https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/5C135321A6617514V
                    },
                    {
                           "method": "POST",
                           "rel": "refund",
                           "href": https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/5C135321A6617514V/refund
                    }
             ],
             "id": "5C135321A6617514V",
             "state": "completed",
             "invoice_number": ""
      },
      "status": "SUCCESS",
      "transmissions": [
             {
                    "webhook_url": https://regolari.azurewebsites.net/RegolariCaller,
                    "http_status": 200,
                    "reason_phrase": "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established",
                    "response_headers": {
                           "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
                           "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
                           "Connection": "keep-alive",
                           "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinitySameSite=2989c34f7c0cdb7ec5c37c2d6a0cd07c20c702dc389fc83ca79bfb532ef0320f;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=regolari.azurewebsites.net",
                           "Date": "Fri, 17 Jun 2022 09:57:41 GMT",
                           "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                           "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET"
                    },
                    "transmission_id": "e11441f0-ee23-11ec-bf74-079e67007b5e",
                    "status": "SUCCESS",
                    "timestamp": "2022-06-17T09:57:20Z"
             }
      ],
      "links": [
             {
                    "href": https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-3YN53862H3003372E-77V7032476059723Y,
                    "rel": "self",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "encType": "application/json"
             },
             {
                    "href": https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-3YN53862H3003372E-77V7032476059723Y/resend,
                    "rel": "resend",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "encType": "application/json"
             }
      ],
      "event_version": "1.0"
}
```

API CALL FOR CHANGE SUBSCRIPTION TO A NEW PLAN

```
POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-3J5HHBY1JHMC/revise

-H "Content-Type: application/json" \

-H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" \

-d '

{ "plan_id": " P-39787693WX5555114MKWE6KI"

}'
```

RESPONSE LOG ON AZURE LOG APPINSIGHT

```
{

               "name": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",

               "message": "The specified resource does not exist.",

               "debug_id": "cff93589c06cd",

               "details": [

                              {

                                             "issue": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",

                                             "description": "Requested resource ID was not found."

                              }

               ],

               "links": [

                              {

                                             "href": https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND,

                                             "rel": "information_link",

                                             "method": "GET"

                              }

               ]

}
```

Comment: The resource that cannot be found is a path parameter (Subscription ID) and/or the Plan ID. Show your entire request and response log.

Comment: Update my question with entire request and log.

 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you created the subscription ID with a different APP/client-id than the one you are attempting to revise the subscription with.

Manage your apps and corresponding client ids in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications